# Can't draw with opengl version greater then 3.1 with SDL

Tags: opengl, sdl-2, glew

I'm making a simple application using OpenGL, GLEW and SDL2 which draws a simple quad on screen (I'm following the example on lazyfoo site with modern OpenGL).
When I use opengl version 3.1 everything works fine, but if I use OpenGL version 3.2+ draw commands don't work (triangle doesn't appear). Does someone know what I am doing wrong?

This is how I setup everything:

```
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) != 0) {

        return false;
    }
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ACCELERATED_VISUAL, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION, 3);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION, 2);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);
    SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DEPTH_SIZE, 24);
m_pWindow = SDL_CreateWindow("Hello World!", 100, 100, 800, 600, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN );
m_pGLContext = SDL_GL_CreateContext(m_pWindow);
    glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
    GLenum glewError = glewInit();
    if (glewError != GLEW_OK)
    {
        return false;
    }

    //Use Vsync
    if (SDL_GL_SetSwapInterval(1) < 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

If you want to check it grab one-file cpp source from http://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/51_SDL_and_modern_opengl/index.php (on site bottom), and try to change version of opengl from 3.1 to 3.2.

Comment: Your hardware supports OpenGL 3.2?

Answer (score 3):

In OpenGL 3.2, the OpenGL profiles were introduced. The *core* profile actually removes all of the deprecated functions, which breaks compaitibily with older GL functions. The *compatibility* profile retains backwards compatibility.

To create "modern" OpenGL context, the extensions like [GLX_create_context](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_create_context.txt) (Unix/X11) or [WGL_create_context](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/wgl_create_context.txt) (Windows) have to be used (and SDL does that for you internally). Citing these extensions specifications gives the answer to your question:

> The attribute name `GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB` requests an OpenGL
>       context supporting a specific *profile* of the API. If the
>       `GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB` bit is set in the attribute value,
>       then a context implementing the *core* profile of OpenGL is
>       returned. If the `GLX_CONTEXT_COMPATIBILITY_PROFILE_BIT_ARB` bit is
>       set, then a context implementing the *compatibility* profile is
>       returned. **If the requested OpenGL version is less than 3.2,
>       `GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB` is ignored and the functionality of the
>       context is determined solely by the requested version.**
>
> [...]
>
> **The default value for `GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB` is
>       `GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB`. All OpenGL 3.2 implementations are
>       required to implement the core profile, but implementation of the
>       compatibility profile is optional.**

SInce you did not explicitely request a *compatibility* profile (and SDL does neither), you got a *core* profile, and it seems like your code is invalid in a core profile.

You might try requesting a compaitbility profile by adding the

```
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK, SDL_GL_CONTEXT_PROFILE_COMPATIBILITY);
```

hint before creating the context.

But be warned that this is not universally supported - MacOS generally supports only GL up to 2.1 OR GL >= 3.2 core profile only. THe open source drivers on Linux only support OpenGL >= 3.2 only in core profile, too. So my recommendation is that you actually fix your code and switch to a core profile.

Comment: Thx for answer, it helps :-) I want to use core profile, but I don't know how can I find functions deprecated in current core profile.